# preg_replace make matched hex value appear as text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to use preg_replace to convert only matching hex values into text representation of hex?

`$string = 'abcd'.hex2bin(23).'abc'.hex2bin(24);`

For example `str_replace('/[\x20-\x25]/', 'what here?', $string)` would get output like:

```
abcd[HEX:23]abc[HEX:24]
```

What exactly I want to do: I'm looking for hidden characters, and want to display their hex values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to have a callback called against all matches.

Try:

```
$string = 'abcd'.hex2bin(23).'abc'.hex2bin(24);

$text = preg_replace_callback('/[\\x20-\\x25]/', function($matches) {
    $string = bin2hex($matches[0]);
    return "[HEX:{$string}]";
}, $string);
```

Comment: Had no idea function like this exists. Thank you. This sovled my problem 100%!